# Jquery animation after long DOM append

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I want to animate a div from right to left. Before that i have to append long dom in it. If i do both together animation is not smooth. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/HTyUf/2/) for live demo.

click "Click 1" - doing a smooth animation.
click "Reset".
click "Click 2" - bad animation.

-Any Help?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div id="main-div" style="display: inline-block">
        <div id="div-1" class="inner-div">
        </div>
        <div id="div-2" class="inner-div" style="left: 300px; background-color: yellow">
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
        <input type="button" value='Call 1' onclick='DoAnimate(15)'/>
        <input type="button" value='Call 2' onclick='DoAnimate(4000)'/>        
        <input type="button" value='Reset' onclick='Reset()'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function DoAnimate(count)
{
    $("#div-2").empty();

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i ++)
    {
        $("#div-2").append("<div> DIV " + i + "</div>");
    }

    $("#div-1").animate({left: -300}, 300);
    $("#div-2").animate({left: 0}, 300);
}

function Reset()
{
    $("#div-2").empty();

    $("#div-1").animate({left: 0}, 300);
    $("#div-2").animate({left: 300}, 300);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#main-div
{
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-div
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You can improve the appending performance by using native DOM API (`documentFragment`s where possible, and avoiding HTML parsing by the browser), but if you only want to wait for the reflow, simply query the object's computed style before requesting the animation.

Comment: It takes a _long_ time to append. You should definitely optimize that as well (if the scenario in the fiddle is realistic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what Jan said.

Append those newly constructed elements to a documentFragment or jQuery object instead of the DOM.

```
    ...
    $("#div-2").empty();
    var $wrapper = $('<div />');
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        $wrapper.append("<div> DIV " + i + "</div>");
    }
    $("#div-2").append($wrapper)    
    ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/72CdX/

Comment: The `$wrapper` approach is much faster than the direct approach but still too slow. Still a nice approach.

Comment: @JanDvorak can we attain more faster than this approach?

Comment: @user10 `documentFragment`s... but I don't have any experience using them. They're not supported by jQuery, so you'll have to delve into the realms of native DOM manipulation (which is always a good learning experience)

Comment: Basically, they act like normal DOM nodes except that they are replaced by their contents when appended anywhere.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks. Let me try that also.

Comment: @ethagnawl I should have been aware while i code to append each and every item into DOM. Thanks for pointing out my carelessness. If i increase 5000 to 10000, still there is a problem. Is there a way to start animation, after everything is finished.

Comment: @ethagnawl setting timeout is good fun... Thanks for trying different possibilities. see this http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/72CdX/1/. Do you know why it is slow? No direct append. But a bulk sting append.

Comment: It's slow because this example is still doing *5000* operations.